# JavaScript Variable in html

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to add a element to a Table via java script where the cells are varibales. For this i wrote below code:

```
$("#AppendAnlagen").parent().append("<tr><td><asp:Label runat='server' text="+args[0]+"/></td></tr>");
```

on the Page i see +args[0]+ and not the value.

Comment: On text attribute you have forgotten simple quotes. Replace `text="+args[0]+"` by `text='"+args[0]+"'`

Comment: I have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On text attribute you have forgotten simple quotes. Replace `text="+args[0]+"` by `text='"+args[0]+"'`